# DBMS in a container/cluster vs data corruption

Tags: postgresql, containers

I am fairly new to db administrations as well as containerization/kubernetes concepts.

I see every here and then containerized/clustering solutions for i.e. running PostgreSQL (i.e. [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/kubernetes/cloud_native_postgresql/interactive_demo).

This conflicts with info I get during my training where it is said that *"**databases can not run into ephemeral enironments like containers to avoid data corruption**"* on container-failure. The same logic should generally apply to Kubernetes clusters alike.

Can anybody clarify how these two points of views play together?

Answer (score 4):

Your training was wrong. In my organisation we've been running containerised databases in production for few years now. Postgres, MySQL, Db2, Clickhouse.

We are not alone: a [survey](https://dok.community/dokc-2021-report/) conducted by the Data on Kubernetes community in September of 2021 found that, of the participating 500 users

> 90% believe [Kubernetes] is ready for stateful workloads, and a large majority (70%) are running them in production with databases topping the list.

The same DBMS program (i.e. the same machine code) doesn't suddenly become more likely to fail if is executed inside a container. Likewise, it doesn't suddenly develop defects that may cause it to corrupt its data.

DBMSes, at least those that you would want to use in production, are already designed to be resilient against crashes and to keep data durable and consistent. All you need to do is use a persistent volume for persistent data. Persistent volumes survive container restarts and recovery is taken care of by the respective database engine, just like it would deal with the regular database process abend.

Comment: I am aware of persitant Volume and what it does (surviving conteriner crashes). I think the argument is that during a crash of a container/pod a current process in memory could be womehwat compromised and likewise corrupt the data. Is that a misinterpretation or false assumption?

Comment: How would that be different from a process crash in a VM or a bare metal machine?

Comment: You probably mean "it's not different the a process crashing in a VM ... " @mustaccio ? If that is so, then the argument may be ... containers are ephemeral by design, so the same bad things as a process crashing in a VM will happen with containers ... just much more likely and likewise more often. So you have a much 'better' chance of corrupting your data then within a VM/bmm.

Comment: This is not an argument, this is a claim for which you provide no grounds. You keep saying these words, "containers are ephemeral by design", but you don't explan why the same application is suddently more likely to abend inside a container. You also don't explain the mechanism by which a terminated application is capable of corrupting its data.

Comment: it is not exactly me saying this. It's more me repeating what my colleagues say (which neither are greek gods, nor total dummies). You are also right that I do not "explain the mechanism by which a terminated application is capable of corrupting its data". This is simply because I am lacking the background for such an explanation also. It seems to be kind of common knowledge that an abrupt power off (maybe similar to a container crashing) bares the risk of data corruption though (whereof again I can not provide proof of). I am here to learn from your arguments actually, not proving you wrong.

Comment: here are some arguments on the topic: [reliably-use-a-database-in-a-container-in-2020](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-reliably-use-a-database-in-a-Docker-container-in-2020), [why-databases-is-not-for-containers](https://myopsblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/06/why-databases-is-not-for-containers/). Again, these are not my arguments to prove anybody wrong. It is to understand the matter and pros/cons. I may be so that such arguments are not valid any longer (in 2021) and that people tend to take them as written in stone, not taking development in container technology into account.

Comment: Abrupt power off, container crash, kernel crash, application crash, it doesn't make much difference for a RDBMS integrity. They are designed to recover and not become corrupted.